# Conditional Processing vs Separate Pages - Which makes sense?

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

I'm building a resource section on a website which will show people different pieces of information such as a guidebooks, blogs, corporate documents. Clearly each of these different information types requires a different layout and feel on the page. A blog page would be very casual, whereas a corporate document would be very formal.

Its got me thinking:

1. Should I have separate pages to deal with the different information
   types e.g. blog.htm, document.htm, guides.htm
2. **OR** Should I have one dynamic page called `information.cfm` for example that will use conditional logic to display each information type differently. So something like:

`<cfif URL.DocType = 'Guide'>
    // Show layout/divs appropriate for Guides
    <cfelseif URL.DocType = 'Corporate'>
    // Show layout/divs appropriate for Corporate documents
    </cfif>`

The second choice makes most sense to me personally, but is this correct?

Comment: I am not aware about coldfusion so I won't be voting to close, but your question sounds like an *opinion based* question to me

Comment: Yes its opinion based in a way. But best-practice is always somewhat opinion based

Comment: I agree this question is opinion based. There are other Stack Exchange sites that may be better suited for it - [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for example.

Comment: You might want to go with both.  Have a single url, but use cfinclude to keep the page from having an overwhelming amount of code.  Having said that, I think Option 1 is better.

Comment: The best practice is using an existing framework that supports layouts.

Comment: @DanBracuk the first option seems easier to manage because the layouts are all seperate and I can design them individually. The second option seems more concise but code switching is going to make designing the look and feel a bit more of a task. Difficult one this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a few possible paper types (lets render them to two specific types).

You have a series of links on a page:

The links look like this:

```
super professional paper 
bloggie type paper
another super duper pro-paper
something real formal
something personal-able and bloggie-ish
```

So say you have index.cfm and along with that you'll have a `header.cfm` and `footer.cfm` included. `index.cfm` the header will be waiting for a url var:  `url.professionalPaper` which will be equal to 0 or 1 depending on the link you build (see below) situation if it is '0' it is 'professional' and if it is '1' it is 'bloggie'.

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm"> in your index.cfm file and
```

In the `header.cfm` put this:

```
<cfparam name="url.professionalPaper" default="-1">
```

Defaulted to '-1' means to 'expect nothing' is coming 9in your thinking).

You'll have a list of links...your list of links will be constructed like this:

```
<a href="?professionalPaper=0&paperID=1234">professionalPaper</a><br>
<a href="?professionalPaper=1&paperID=1111">something personalable and bloggie</a>
```

if you want to use the page you are in which is currently `index.cfm` you can do something like this:

```
<cfif structkeyExists(url,"paperID")>
    Hi you are reading a paper...but which one?
    <cfswitch expression="#url.professionalPaper#">
        <cfcase value="0">
            Yep we are a pro-paper just out the professional!
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="1">
            This is a touchy feel blog post.  I feel weepy.
        </cfcase>
        <cfdefaultcase>
            Wait what?  -1 in url.professionalPaper you need to pick a paper!
        </cfdefaultcase>
    </cfswitch>
</cfif>
<br>
Here are some links:<br>
<a href="?professionalPaper=0&paperID=1234">professionalPaper</a><br>
<a href="?professionalPaper=1&paperID=1111">something personal-able and bloggie</a>
```

This is the basic premise...and you can alter it to suit your needs.

If you wanted to point this to a catch page like say: pages.cfm then change your links.

```
<a href="pages.cfm?professionalPaper=0&paperID=1234">professionalPaper</a><br>
<a href="pages.cfm?professionalPaper=1&paperID=1111">something personalable and bloggie</a>
```

And fill the rest of the logic into that page instead. That way you have links in index.cfm and your pages logic in `pages.cfm`.

Then your defaultcase statement can read like this:

```
<cfdefaultcase>
    Wait what?  -1 in url.professionalPaper you need to need to go back (link to go back to your index.cfm page of links).
</cfdefaultcase>

This is a high level treatment but I think you get the gist and I bet you can build on it too :)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to check FW/1 or any other MVC framework, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, it's all been done before:

https://github.com/framework-one/fw1

Comment: I don't like the idea of having 1 index.cfm page to serve ALL my website. It just doesn't work for me.

Comment: FW/1 does not use 1 index.cfm page. It has separate folders/files for layouts, views, services, etc.

Comment: FW/1 is the bomb but this OP seems to be requesting a simpler solution.  Frameworks would halt the ship mid sail.  Too much for a conceptual presentation management question.